# What is the name for a description which is not true but is common place?

Tags: meaning

A standard electrocardiogram is called a '12-lead ecg' even though it only actually uses 10 leads. Is there a name for such a phrase?

(I know there is a reason behind the example I have given, but in your answer please can you assume there isn't a reason and it is just badly named)

Comment: That's called a *misnomer*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jim says in a comment, the word **misnomer** is probably what you're looking for. From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/misnomer):

> 1. a misapplied or inappropriate name or designation.
> 2. an error in naming a person or thing.